# parsing data from dota2protracker

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get the data about new matches from dota2protracker. New matches in html starts with `row-0`[image]

But using this code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'User-Agent': f'{ua.random}'
}

soup = BeautifulSoup()

page = requests.get('https://dota2protracker.com/hero/Anti-Mage#', headers=headers)
print(page.text)
```

The first match has class `row-37`[image]

Why the data isn't new and how to fix that?